# Powershell 5 Copy-Item Directory to Directory Error

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I am new to Powershell, and am testing out the functionality of `Copy-Item` according to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-6). I am trying to copy files and folders from a subfolder into it's containing folder, but it is not working. What command do I need to use?

Here is my sample file structure

```
C:\
    Example
    |
    |__Top
        |
        |__Middle
            |
            |__Bottom
```

I tried to copy all the files and subfolders from `Middle` into `Top` using

```
Copy-Item "C:\Example\Top\Middle" -Destination "C:\Example\Top" -Recurse
```

but received this error

```
Copy-Item : An item with the specified name C:\Example\Top\Middle already exists.
At line:1 char:1
+ Copy-Item "C:\Example\Top\Middle" -Destination "C:\Example\Top" -Recu ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (C:\Example\Top\Middle:String) 
[Copy-Item], IO
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
DirectoryExist,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Copy-Item : Cannot overwrite the item C:\Example\Top\Middle\InTheMiddle.txt 
with itself.
At line:1 char:1
+ Copy-Item "C:\Example\Top\Middle" -Destination "C:\Example\Top" -Recu ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: 
(C:\Example\Top\Middle\InTheMiddle.txt:String) [Co
   py-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
CopyError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Copy-Item : An item with the specified name C:\Example\Top\Middle\Bottom already         
exists.
At line:1 char:1
+ Copy-Item "C:\Example\Top\Middle" -Destination "C:\Example\Top" -Recu ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: 
(C:\Example\Top\Middle\Bottom:String) [Copy-It
   em], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
DirectoryExist,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Copy-Item : Cannot overwrite the item 
C:\Example\Top\Middle\Bottom\InTheBottom.txt with
itself.
At line:1 char:1
+ Copy-Item "C:\Example\Top\Middle" -Destination "C:\Example\Top" -Recu ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: 
(C:\Example\Top\...InTheBottom.txt:String) [Copy-I
   tem], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
CopyError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Powershell Version 5.1.17134.112 Running as Administrator

Comment: The error literally explains the problem to you. The Middle folder ***already exists*** in the Top folder.

Comment: I am trying to copy the _contents_ of the middle folder into the top folder, not create a new folder or override the old one. How do I do that?

Comment: Then you want `C:\Example\Top\Middle\*.*`

Comment: Okay, that Copied the files inside `Middle` but not the folders. How do I copy all subfolders? Are there any other similar codes and where can I look them up?

Comment: @Aposhian *I am trying to copy the contents of the middle folder* No. Your code literally says "copy the folder 'Middle' to its parent folder 'Top'". Where it already exists, hence the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You trying to copy child folder to its parent folder. To copy content of "Middle" folder you need to use this command:

```
Copy-Item "C:\Example\Top\Middle\*" -Destination "C:\Example\Top" -Recurse
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there somewhere where I can read about the difference between `*` and `*.*` or any additional codes?

Comment: Check this article -  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2017/06/04/wildcards-in-windows/

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will accomplish what you are looking for as the simplest example. It would need tweaked depending on your scenario.

-Force would need applied to overwrite.

```
$source = "C:\Example\Top\Middle\*"

$destination = "C:\Example\Top\"

Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination -Include *.*
```

Comment: What does `-Include *.*` do? Is that for hidden files?

Comment: It allows the flexibility to be able to narrowly tailor the files you would like to copy by the name disregarding the extension and vice versa